# Storing multiple variables in a single $_SESSION(PHP)

Tags: php, session, authentication

How would I make this work, I asked before and didn't get a correct answer. This code is the user login, so when they log in I want username and avatar to be trackable through out the site. So far I just have username. I have tried methods and have failed every time.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) 
{
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   while ($_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'])
   {
      session_start();
      header('Location: index.php'); 
   }
}
else
{
   echo 'Invalid Logins';
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `while ($_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'])
{
session_start();
header('Location: index.php'); ` --- where did you get this terrible code? o_O

Comment: Stop inserting dynamic input right into the query, use bind variables instead.

Comment: This code was from my instructor.

Comment: @Garrett Robertson: you need find another one urgently. That guy doesn't understand what he does

Comment: Well, this simple fix kinda' opens my eyes to redundant code... uneeded code. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have avatar stored in the `avatar` field in the database:

```
if ($count == 1) 
{
    session_start();

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];

    header('Location: index.php'); 
}
else
{
    echo 'Invalid Logins';
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it really was that simple. People kept telling me all this complicated stuff that seemed to be over doing it. Thanks again!